# If $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is RCLL adapted process, then left limit process $(X_{-t})_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is locally bounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Assume $X=(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a RCLL adapted process. I set $X_{-t}:=\lim_{s \rightarrow t, s < t}X_s$ for $t \in (0,\infty)$ and $X_{-0}=0$. I want to show that $(X_{-t})_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is locally bounded. I tried defining a stopping time by setting

$$\tau_n := \inf\{t \in [0,\infty) : |X_t| \geq n \}.$$

Then $(\tau_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a stopping time by adaptedness and the RCLL property of $X$. And also for every $\omega \in \Omega$, we have for $t>0$ that

\begin{align}
|X_{-t}^{\tau_n(\omega)}(\omega)1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}(\omega)|&=|X_{-t}^{\tau_n(\omega)}(\omega)|1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}(\omega) \\\\
&= |\lim_{s \rightarrow t \wedge \tau_n(\omega), s < t \wedge \tau_n(\omega)}X_s(\omega) |1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}\\\\
&=\lim_{s \rightarrow t \wedge \tau_n(\omega), s < t \wedge \tau_n(\omega)}|X_s(\omega) |1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}} \\\\
&\leq n
\end{align}

And clearly by definition, this also holds for $t=0$, since we set it to $0$ there. Now whats missing, is to show that $\tau_n(\omega) \rightarrow \infty$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

**But I do not see how I can deduce that. Can someone help? Is the approach with my stopping time even the right one?**

Thanks a lot?

Comment: This follows simply from the fact that any cadlag function $f$ is bounded on compact intervals, i.e. $$\forall T>0: \quad \sup_{s \in [0,T]} |f(s)| < \infty.$$

Comment: Oh yes now I see it. I did not think about boundedness of cad lag functions on a compact interval. If repost this comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @saz Does this mean that any càdlàg process $X$ is locally bounded,  meaning that there exists an increasing sequence of stopping times $(t_n)\rightarrow \infty$ and a sequence $\alpha_n$ such that $X 1_{]]0,t_n]]}\leq \alpha_n$, for all $n$?